# How to append Dropzone return value to Form Data

Tags: jquery, ajax, dropzone.js

I have an Ajax that submit form data with laravel validation.

```
$('body').on('click', '#submit', function(){
 var form_data = new FormData($('form')[1]);

 $.ajax({
     url:'/admin/products/',
     type:'POST',
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     dataType: 'json',
     data:form_data,
     success:function(data) {

     },
 });
```

then also Dropzone file upload/remove in separate Ajax url.

```
<div id="fileInput" class="dropzone">
    <input name="p_file" type="file" multiple />
</div>

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
new Dropzone('#fileInput', {
    // paramName: 'p_file',
    url: "/admin/products/upload",
    // autoProcessQueue: false,
    addRemoveLinks: true,

    init: function () {
        var myDropzone = this;
        myDropzone.on('success', function (file, serverResponse) {
            var fileuploded = file.previewElement.querySelector("[data-dz-name]");
            fileuploded.innerHTML = serverResponse;
        });

        myDropzone.on('removedfile', function(file, response) {
            var name = file.previewElement.querySelector('[data-dz-name]').innerHTML;
        });

        sending: function (file, xhr, formData) {
            // formData.append("name", $('#name').val());
        }
})
```

According to documentation, I have to use this to do normal form submission.

```
sending: function (file, xhr, formData) {
        // formData.append("name", $('#name').val());
    }
```

but I would like to append Dropzone value into form_data of first Ajax, instead of append other form_data to Dropzone as in documentation.
How can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

assign the dropzone file into one varialbe then add it to FormData object

```
$('body').on('click', '#submit', function(){
var fileUpload = $('#fileInput').get(0).dropzone;
var files = fileUpload.files;
var form_data= new FormData();

// Looping over all files and add it to FormData object  
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        form_data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
    }

 $.ajax({
     url:'/admin/products/',
     type:'POST',
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     dataType: 'json',
     data:form_data,
     success:function(data) {

     },
 });
```